# How do we just select lists from the imported module?

Tags: python, loops, directory, iterator

Let's say I did the following:

```
from X import A, B, C, D
```

What I want to do is that combine all lists in A, B, C, D to make a single big list:

```
all_list=[]     
for each_variable in (X.A, X.B, X.C, X.D combined):
    if each_variable is a list:
        all_list.extend(each_list)
```

Is there an easy way to do it in python?

For instance, X.A may contain some lists, some dictionaries, etc, and same for X.C, X.D.

I was wondering if python has modules that can detect data type within each module and only select that.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of the data contained in the lists and the result you expect?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no such way in python to combine only particular datatypes from lists in other lists. The approach you are using looks fine.

Answer (score -1):

## How to concatenate lists

### Use itertools.chain

Use itertools.chain (https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to iterate over several iterables.

```py
import itertools

all_list = []
for each_element in itertools.chain(X.A, X.B, X.C, X.D):
    all_list.append(each_element)
```

BTW, I'd recommend list comprehension.

### Use a tuple of lists

```py
all_list = []
for each_list in (X.A, X.B, X.C, X.D):
    all_list.extend(each_list)
```

BTW, I'd recommend list comprehension.

### Use unpacking

```py
all_list = [*X.A, *X.B, *X.C, *X.C]
```